# Move, en-masse, reports from system folder 'Public Folder' to another folder

Tags: reports-api, reports-folder

Using the API, I am unable to move/copy the reports in the system folder 'Public Report' en masse.
In workbench I find all folders except the 'Public Folder', can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Unfiled Public Reports folder API name is `unfiled$public`